# When was a file last accessed in Windows 7

Tags: events, viewer

Is it possible to see when a text file is opened on Windows 7?

I looked in the with Event Viewer a little bit but I couldn't find where to see the logs about a specific text file being accessed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ### When was a file last accessed  in Windows

You should note the below and if you have this enabled then you can find the file properties attribute of **Last Accessed**:

> For improved file system performance, **Last Access time update is
>   switched off since Windows Vista by default (also, Windows 2008 / 2008
>   R2, Windows 7). Thus, Last Access time attribute is set upon creating
>   file and not changed afterwards even if file is modified.** However, it
>   is possible to enable Last Access time updates if necessary.
>
> To enable updates, open Registry Editor by typing regedit in Search
>   input on Start Menu, locate
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` path
>   entry and change `NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate` value data to 0. After
>   this change, the system has to be restarted. Alternatively, run the
>   following command with administrator rights:
>
> [image]
>
> `fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0`
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.febooti.com/products/filetweak/online-help/file-last-accessed-date.html)</sub>

Right-click on the file and select **Properties**

[image]

From the **General** tab you will see the **Last Accessed** attributes

[image]

Comment: You have good chances to accidentally access the file while before opening the properties dialog. (e.g. by windows explorer creating a thumbnail or reading embedded metadata)

Comment: Or perhaps by right-clicking the file and clicking **Properties**??

Comment: @Spittin'IT LOL, no, I was wondering if by accessing the file's Properties dialog one might ironically trigger an update of the Last Accessed timestamp.

Comment: @Twisty I might try to test this on a Win 7 machine at some point toggling the reg key to see what results I get either way--good thought!! If you wanted to be real slick, I suppose you could look into the NTFS MFT records or USN Journals regardless of what the OS does, so I wonder what would show at this level, but I won't get that sophisticated with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on the text file and click on Properties, from there, it will tell you when it was last accessed.

Comment: Not [by default](https://superuser.com/a/1109655/213131) it won't...

Answer (score 0):

If you do enable that filesystem option (by default it isn't, as discussed in previous answers), then this command will show the last accessed time:

```
wmic DataFile where "Name='C:\\Users\\Default\\NTUSER.DAT'"
```